# How to read char from the console

Tags: c#, console, char, console.readline

I have a `char` array and I want to assign values from the console. Here's my code:

```
char[] input = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    input[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' to 'char'

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Did you have a look at what `System.ConsoleKeyInfo` is? Hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then `KeyChar` to get `char`, because [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not assignable to `char` as your error says.

```
input[i] = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Comment: Fails if stdin comes from a file though.

Answer (score 2):

Quick example to play around with:

```
    public static void DoThis(int n)
    {
        var input = new char[n];
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            input[i] = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(); // Linebreak
        Console.WriteLine(input);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the first character of the String being returned by Console.ReadLine()

```
char[] input = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    input[i] = Console.ReadLine()[0];
}
```

This will throw away all user input other than the first character.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int MyAnswer(int n)
{
  int[] ac = new int[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < ac.Length; i++) {
  
  ac[i] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  Console.WriteLine(ac[i]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```