# c# - How to read char from the console and write them?

Tags: c#

Sorry, I've just started programming in C#. I would like to know what's the easiest way to read a character or characters from the console and store the value into a variable to be written to the console at a later point.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with any of the `Console` class API? Like, `Console.Read` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read char from the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860677/how-to-read-char-from-the-console)

Comment: @MarkC. Not really, I'm really at the beginning of  learn the programming. Thank you for quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There's much more of a learning opportunity here for the OP than just answering the question, in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkC. You are absolutely correct! I just wanted to do him a favor and give him a quick starting point.

Comment: Sure, and I agree with you, but teaching OP that they could go to the `Console` class and look at the API with notes could lead to some valuable learning (I am assuming that they didn't know that they could do that). +1 anyway. Cheers!