# In C# I am taking a char input and then I output something. But after input control is not waiting for enter and straightaway giving output

Tags: c#, char, console.readline, console.readkey

I have the following code:

using System;

```
namespace MyApp {
class KeyBoardInputTest {
    static void Main() {
        Console.Write("Enter a character >\t");
        char ch = (char)Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if(Char.IsLetter(ch)) {
            if(Char.IsUpper(ch))
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an upper case character");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered a lower case character");
        }
        else if(Char.IsNumber(ch))
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered a numeric character");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered a non alpha-numeric character");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

After taking an input such as <kbd>a</kbd> it is straightaway showing result without waiting for me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Using `Console.ReadLine()` gives the error -

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'char'
```

Using `Console.ReadKey()` gives the error -

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' to 'char'
```

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, this post can probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860677/how-to-read-char-from-the-console

Comment: Just why do you need to have and enter?

Comment: Nothing, just having some extra C# skills to do some manevouring :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example try-parse:

```
Console.Write("Enter a character >\t");
char ch;
char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ch);
Console.WriteLine();
```

You will get the null character `'\0'` if the user types too many characters, or no characters, before Enter. Alternatively, you can pick up the return value of `TryParse`, a boolean telling whether the parsing succeeded.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please explain the meaning of "char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ch);"? I am new to C#.

Comment: @puregeek The method `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string` which is like a whole text consisting of many characters. You could have used that directly, as in `string st = Console.WriteLine();`, but then you would modify the rest of your program. Instead I used the `TryParse` method which checks whether it is possible to "see" the `string` as a `char`. When it succeeds, it puts its result in the `out` parameter. When it fails, it does not blow up, it just puts the zero character `'\0'` into that `out` variable.

Comment: That means if for example, I input "ab" instead of "a" and then press enter then '\0' gets stored in out? @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: @puregeek Yes! We get `char.TryParse("ab", out ch)`, and it will not parse, and you get `'\0'`. An alternative, with `using System.Linq;` added at the top, would be just `char ch = Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault();` which takes the first character of the string, and only resorts to `'\0'` in the case where the string has no characters (the empty string, when user presses Enter immediately).

Comment: As a side note, it is a request, can you please say, can we assign octal literal to byte? @JeppeStigNielsen

Answer (score 0):

Consider pivoting your code to accept input as arguments and convert the input to a char using the System class Convert.ToChar()

```
using System;

namespace MyApp {

class KeyBoardInputTest {
static void Main(string [] args) {    // This line has been changed
    Console.Write("Enter a character >\t");
    char ch = Convert.ToChar(args[0])   // This line has been changed
    Console.WriteLine("");

    if(Char.IsLetter(ch)) {
        if(Char.IsUpper(ch))
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an upper case character");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered a lower case character");
    }
    else if(Char.IsNumber(ch))
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered a numeric character");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered a non alpha-numeric character");
    Console.Read();
}
}
}
```

Comment: But it will not wait for input, or get input, from the console. Taking parameters from the command line is something else. Also, `Convert.ToChar` will blow up if the string is not length one.

Comment: Giving error (5,31): error CS1552: Array type specifier, [], must appear before parameter name and (7,37): error CS1002: ; expected

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the first character of the String which Console.ReadLine() returns

```
namespace MyApp {
class KeyBoardInputTest {
    static void Main() {
        Console.Write("Enter a character >\t");
        char ch = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if(Char.IsLetter(ch)) {
            if(Char.IsUpper(ch))
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an upper case character");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered a lower case character");
        }
        else if(Char.IsNumber(ch))
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered a numeric character");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered a non alpha-numeric character");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Keep in mind this removes any additional characters the user may have entered. It will also cause an IndexOutOfRangeException if you the user does not enter any information.

Answer (score 0):

For a Dirtier, but very flexible code, you can use Try-Catch to get the input.

Make sure that you initialize the variable with something like:
`ch = 'c';`

Then use this piece of code:

```
    try()          //You can get the try-catch code snippet by typing 'try' and hit enter or tab
    {
       ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a Valid Character");  //You can also recurse your function after this
    }
```

This method is a bit Unclean, but you still can do a lot more in it as compared to other ways. (Like calling a function inside 'catch' or 'try').