# Why can't i convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius?

Tags: c#

My C# code keeps returnng me a wrong conversion result. As far as i know, the conversion formula is correct, but it keeps displaying wrong results.

e.g: 70°F gives me 12,777777 °C.  Can you check my code out ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Temperature
{
    class Program
    {    
        class Temperature
        {
            public double temp;

            public void Convert(double value)
            {
                double tEmp;
                tEmp = (value - 32) / 1.8;
                Console.WriteLine("The temperature in °C is :" + tEmp);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double f;
            Temperature c = new Temperature();
            f = Console.Read();
            c.Convert(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: Formula is `(°F  -  32)  x  5/9 = °C`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman what's the difference?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev: Just for people that don't do this every day. Like me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It does. If you try running this program, you will get the described result. However, this problem could be solved by simply setting a breakpoint inside `Convert` and seeing what `value` is.

Comment: @GrantWinney: It would make the search query for google a much more practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.Read()` returns the **ordinal** value of the next character in the input stream.

The first character in your input stream is `'7'` which has an ordinal value of `0x0037`. Represented as decimal this is `55` and `(55-32)/1.8` is `12.7777`.

You should be using `Console.ReadLine()` rather than `Console.Read()`.

Answer (score 13):

your problem is

```
f = Console.Read();
```

It just reads the first character, not your entire line of input. Try

```
f = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline) a good answer on the difference between `Console.Read` vs. `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: Correct, this is the source of the problem, but you should explain *why* `Console.Read` of `70` gives `12.78` instead of `21.11`

Comment: Console.Read returns an Int32 which represents a single character that was read or -1. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read

Comment: Thanks. I didin't know about the "Convert.ToDouble" method.