# How to read more than two numbers beside each other?

Tags: c#

I want to enter a number from console but i want't beside each other .
For example:-

```
 int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
 int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Example for input:-

3

4

And , want't to display like that:-

3 4

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Split`:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
var parts = input.Split(' ');
x = int.Parse(parts[0]);
y = int.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Notice that I didn't take care of cases where the input doesn't have the space not if it can't be parsed into a number.

- For the spaces - if it is for sure one a single space you want then you can check that the length is of 2. If you want any amount of numbers then use linq's `Select` on the `.Split`
- For the parsing - check `TryParse`

Comment: This would work too

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine()` reads input until a user hits the enter key, which will advance the cursor to the next line.

You want `Console.Read()` or perhaps `Console.ReadKey()`.  Just keep in mind that you'll have to implement logic to determine when input is ended - for example, checking whether the input was the space key, or some other non-numeric key.  `ReadLine` is handling that for you automatically right now, whereas `Read/ReadKey` will not.

See also: [Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline)