# Console.read(); not lets me input any value and sets variable value to 13

Tags: c#, console

i have some execution issues, where the same function is not working in the same way

```
while(mano.Count != 0)    // inizio partita
            {
                int count = 0;
                scelta = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()) -48;
                string res = cl.Colleziona(mano[scelta - 1], ID);                    
                while (res == "Non e' il tuo turno" || res.StartsWith("Il tuo avversario ha giocato: "))
                {
                    if (res.StartsWith("Il tuo avversario ha giocato: "))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(res + ", seleziona di nuovo una carta: ");                           
                        scelta = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());  //here gives the error
                        res = cl.Colleziona(mano[scelta-1], ID);
                        Console.WriteLine(res);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(res);
                        count++;
                    }                        
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    res = cl.Colleziona(mano[scelta - 1], ID);
                }                    
                mano.Remove(mano[scelta-1]);
                ris = cl.partita();
                while (ris == null)
                {                      
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    ris = cl.partita();              
                }
```

The commented function returns 13 instead of letting me input something, giving OutOfRangeException on the successive function, any solution?

Thanks

Comment: can you add it as a answer? so i can mark this as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wanted to call  [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx). This returns the whole line as a string whereas [`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) returns an int that represents one character at a time.

In this case, 13 represents the carriage return - you likely hit enter after typing your first bit of input.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline) covers the difference between the various `Console.ReadX` methods in more detail.