# Difference between Console.ReadLine and Console.In.ReadLine

Tags: c#, .net, console, console.readline

I came across these two APIs to read input from user in a simple console application in C#:

- `System.Console.ReadLine()`
- `System.Console.In.ReadLine()`

Here is a small code snippet where I'm trying to leverage these two:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
            var input2 = System.Console.In.ReadLine();
         }
    }
}
```

When I run this program, the two lines of code are doing exactly the same thing i.e. whatever string I type on console is returned till the time I hit the return key. A quick googling fetched me only one link which [differentiates between Console.Read and Console.ReadLine APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6825943/465053). Can anyone help me in understanding the significance of these two separate APIs doing the same thing i.e. to receive user input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Is an Alias for

```
System.Console.In.ReadLine()
```

So they are exactly the same.

Here is the code for ReadLine in Microsoft reference source.

```
[HostProtection(UI=true)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static String ReadLine()
{
    return In.ReadLine();
}
```

As you can see Console.ReadLine() just calls Console.In.ReadLine().

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,bc8fd98a32c60ffd

Answer (score 2):

I would really just comment, but I do not have permissions.

These both links are explaining it very good. Look at examples to see a kind of production.

- [Console.Out Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.console.out(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the **standard output stream**.

- [Console.In Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.console.in(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the **standard input stream**.

Here an another link to the [Console.WriteLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx)
It describes well, that it uses the **standard output stream**, so it means **Console.Out**.

> Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to
>   the **standard output stream**.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. You've the comment rights from now. Good luck with your journey on stackoverflow.