# The ? operator isn't working correctly instead of if/else

Tags: c#

I was trying to put the `?` operator in my code instead of the usual if /else 
but it gave me the same result whether it's true or false?

```
int student_grade;
Console.WriteLine("enter the grade:");
student_grade = Console.Read();

Console.WriteLine((student_grade >= 60) ? "passed" :"failed");
```

Comment: How about debugging your program?

Comment: Did you step through in the debugger to make sure `student_grade` actually got the correct value?

Comment: the debbuger shows no errors !!!

Comment: @SeifWalid Can you print the value of student_grade also ?

Comment: Then edit your question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, complete with what input you give, and what output you get. See [ask]

Comment: What does [`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) return? Hint:  Do you get the correct result when you enter `1`?

Comment: I strongly recommend you read "*[Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline)*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Console.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns an ASCII value of the first character in your input. Try your code with the letter "A" as input - result will be “passed", because the ASCII value for "A" is 65.  It just so happens that numbers 0-9 have ASCII values 48-57, respectively; your code compares to 60, so the result is always the same.

Converting after the input will not work; you need to use `Console.ReadLine()`, and parse the input as `int`

Comment: I'd suggest explaining *why* `A` will give the result it does.

Comment: Since .NET doesn't use ASCII, "Reads the next character from the standard input stream" means the next [`Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.7.2) value (UTF-16 code unit). UTF-16 is one of several character encodings of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Unicode "A"  (U+0041) is encoded by UTF-16 as `'\u0041'`, which has the decimal value of 65.