# char c = getc(stdin); c != -EOF in C#

Tags: c#

What is the C# equivalent of the following C++ code?

```
for (char c = getc(stdin); c != -1; c = getc(stdin))
            if (c == '\n' || c == '\r')
                continue;
            else
                str[p++] = c;
        str[p] = 0;
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a C++ compiler but this is pure C.

Comment: Whatever it is, it will have to be just as buggy as the C version, since the C version is broken. Maybe you shouldn't pay much attention to C (not C++) code that's broken by design.

Comment: Look at Console.ReadLine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = new StringBuilder();
for (int c = Console.Read(); c != -1; c = Console.Read())
{
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\r')
        continue;
    str.Append((char)c);
}
string s = str.ToString();
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but it doesn't work

I need replace just char c = getc(stdin)

Comment: @DanilSitnikov What is mean by doesn't work? are you facing any error? any exception? kindly explain what is not working?

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar When I try to pass the task I get a Runtime error (integer division by zero), but in c++ I passed, but I must pass in c#

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2520121.html#post13940078

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate through user input character and if it is `\n` (`\n` stands for new line) and `\t`(`\t` stands for tab/four blank spaces) then skip it otherwise add it to existing string

In C#, we use [`Console.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_Read) to read next character from console, you can use this to read next character from console input, update your code as per your loop and condition.

@Henk used [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) to avoid creating new string everytime, as `StringBuilder` class is mutable.

You can use @HenkHolterman solution to solve your problem, but this answer will help you to understand his code.

Comment: And is there a way to enter -1, to end this iteration ? Looks like an endless loop to me.

Comment: @Holger: Ctrl-Z gives -1. And that is the sole reason that Read() returns int and not char.