# Print text on same line as user input using C# Console

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to use C#'s `Console.ReadLine()` method to take user input from the console, then subsequently print text on the same line.

Code being used:

```cs
using System;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(" out");
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting from the console:

```
in out
```

What's actually being produced:

```
in
 out
```

Note that `in` here is being typed into the console.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

-chris

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to use `Console.Read()`, not `Console.ReadLine()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-7.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline)

Comment: @JimG. Yes, and no. I do realize now that I should be using `Console.ReadLine()`, but using that method instead of `Console.Read()` yields the same results. I've edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: You will need to use an input method that doesn’t echo what the user types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it automatically echoes the user input, including the newline when the enter key is pressed. So you have to stop it from echoing the input and handle that yourself.

You can do this by using [`Console.ReadKey(Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-7.0#system-console-readkey(system-boolean)) and passing `true` to intercept the key, and only write it to the output if it's not the enter key.

That would look like this:

```
using System;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            while (true) {
                var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" out");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this would however not handle special keys like Backspace or cursor keys as the user might expect