# Assigning an integer to Console.Read

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# but I've been trying to learn.

How can I assign an integer to `Console.Read()`?

This is my code:

```
 const int MINE = 2;
 Console.WriteLine("How many points did you lose?");
 
 int points;
 points = Console.Read();
 Console.ReadLine();
 if (points < MINE)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("You lost fewer points than me.");
 }
 else if (points > MINE) 
 {
     Console.WriteLine("You lost more points than me.");
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("You lost the same number of points as me.");
 }
```

When I run the program it only responds with "You lost more points than me", regardless of the number I enter. Please help.

I tried to not include Console.ReadLine() because I'm only assigning integers so far, and Console.ReadLine() is used for string if I'm not wrong. But I've been seeing other answers say that using Console.ReadLine() will help.

How can I fix my line code? Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline

Comment: `Console.Read()` console reads 1 character, not a string that is converted to an integer. You can use a single `Console.ReadLine` instead and parse the string with `int.TryParse`

Comment: The `int` you get back from `Console.Read` is the character code, not an intuitive interpretation of a numeric character you happen to type.  Refer to an ASCII table for character codes.  (Hint: Typing a character that's `< 2` is unlikely to happen.)

Comment: @David I'm picky but the code could be non ASCII, for instance with `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;` and code > 127